# Google earth incorrectly rendering coordinates?

Tags: kml, google-earth, coordinates, latitude-longitude

My circles are rendering funky on the poles, and along the equator.

#### Here are my coordinates:

```
158.05553767833,-78.151355482613
152.68654993135,-76.924955252783
147.72303124605,-75.713526831152
143.06274497048,-74.524895329406
138.63332012974,-73.365493766502
134.38233416968,-72.240817945152
130.27100948566,-71.155701792104
126.27011840531,-70.11448759429
122.35726277966,-69.121132703464
118.51502708319,-68.179276670913
114.72969830909,-67.292283062004
110.9903610723,-66.463264689784
107.28824575653,-65.695097793865
103.61625023098,-64.990428769143
99.968582435602,-64.351675871499
96.340488248312,-63.781027589248
92.728040190375,-63.280438894499
89.127969904661,-62.851626275065
85.537532303713,-62.496062233228
81.954392666042,-62.214969784592
78.376530286024,-62.009317375003
74.802153890611,-61.879814541074
71.229625140461,-61.826908561053
67.657387272327,-61.85078227176
64.083896401248,-61.951353160458
60.507553237337,-62.128273775806
56.926633008616,-62.380933438
53.339211222379,-62.708461163863
49.743082525748,-63.109729656798
46.135669299876,-63.583360142432
42.513915669083,-64.127727755403
38.87416120926,-64.740967096403
35.211986616615,-65.420977473287
31.522020664857,-66.165427203563
27.797693492691,-66.971756167889
24.030914923935,-67.837175533906
20.211647006764,-68.758663165469
16.327325438369,-69.732952609442
12.362061986503,-70.756512568067
8.2955243178175,-71.825512172637
4.1013320161292,-72.935764736584
-0.25528729388528,-74.082638186513
-4.8209969442254,-75.260912557308
-9.6596917885399,-76.464550923909
-14.860832875137,-77.686324272452
-20.55272215938,-78.917181740079
-26.923940644354,-80.145162642771
-34.257840694438,-81.353462558233
-42.985222847202,-82.516927422837
-53.749206371382,-83.595765562688
-67.414565058046,-84.525376429557
-84.75320323954,-85.205991865779
-105.36439351601,-85.51452525361
-126.6349523656,-85.372691897859
-145.37174704566,-84.818624018911
-160.36597119513,-83.969463910769
-172.11759253603,-82.937731923535
178.47360903516,-81.800519081463
170.67339362215,-80.605603613521
163.97799351745,-79.38273857854
158.05553767833,-78.151355482613
```

#### And here is the result:

[image: Result]

**What could be causing this and how can can I fix it?**

Comment: Hint: have you noticed that the problem occurs at the break between -172 and +178?

Comment: Do you mind chatting with me here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6005/meandwhuber

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: google earth rendered the length between those two lines as that circle because it was going around the pole.